# Proof of closed set

Tags: general-topology

I had today a discussion with my professor about A being closed or not

let $ A = \left \{ {(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x>0 , y\geq 1/x} \right \} $

I claim A is not closed since $ (x,y) = (\frac{1}{n+1}, n+1)\in A  \xrightarrow[n\rightarrow + \infty]{} (0, n+1)\notin A $, therefore A is not closed.
Could you enlighten me how A is closed, our professor showed us some proof that I don't accept, because it supposes A closed in first place and then does the whole proof around that and claiming that our hypothesis is right.

Comment: $(\frac{1}{n+1}, n+1)$ does not tend to $(0, n+1)$ (that means nothing), it tends to $(0, +\infty)$ (which is not an element of $A$).

Comment: All right, I see.

Comment: Please post Prof's proof.

Answer (score 3):

As $n \to \infty$, the point $(\frac1{n+1}, n+1)$ does not converge to any point in $\mathbb R^2$, since its $y$-coordinate goes off to $+\infty$. In particular, it cannot converge to $(0,n+1)$ because $n+1$ does not exist as a variable outside the limit you're taking!

We can describe the set $\{(x,y) : x>0, y \ge \frac1x\}$ equally well as the set $\{(x,y) : x \ge 0, xy \ge 1\}$ and since these inequalities are preserved by taking limits, the set is closed.

Comment: Is that $x\ge0$ or $x>0$?

Comment: The second description has $x \ge 0$. I want a non-strict inequality so that it's clear that it remains true in the limit. However, no point with $x=0$ will satisfy the second inequality, $xy \ge 1$.

Comment: Thank you, now that's a proof I accept.

Comment: Very nice!  Thank you

Comment: @mjw I saw that you asked me to post the prof's proof. I will after I'm done with my exams this week ;)

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle \forall x_0>0, B_{x_0}=(x_0,y) \text{ with } y\ge \frac{1}{x_0}$ is closed.

To show that $B_{x_0}$ is closed, we can express, $B_{x_0}^C$, the complement of $B_{x_0}$ as a finite union of open sets.

$\displaystyle B^C_{x_0} $ is the union of three half planes:

$\displaystyle B^C_{x_0} =  \{ (x,y)\in\text{Reals}|x<x_0\} \bigcup 
\left\{(x,y)\in\text{Reals}|x>x_0\right\} \bigcup 
\left\{(x,y)\in\text{Reals}|y<1/x_0\right\} .$

Thus, $\displaystyle A=\bigcup_{x_0 \in \{x>0\}} B_{x_0}$ is closed.

Comment: Could you clarify the form/view of its complement, please?

Comment: Sure.  Will do $\cdots$

Comment: @VIVID, is it still unclear?

Comment: Nope, everything is fine now. Thanks for notifying me.